# Show that If $B\subset R$ be a Borel set then $t+B$ also be Borel set. for any $t\in R$. where R is real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Show that If $B\subset R$ be a Borel set then $t+B$ also be Borel set. for any $t\in R$. where R is real numbers.

I define $A= \{t+B\ is\ borel \ set\ such\ that\ t\in R \}$

Goal- Show that A is a sigma algebra contaning open sets.

First- I need show A is a $\sigma$ algebra.

Is this method correct?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: You have explained it very well. Thank you. I'll do those stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct. Here it is in more details:

> Show that if $B\subseteq \Bbb R$ is a Borel set then $t+B$ also is a Borel set, for any $t\in \Bbb R$. where $\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers.

**Proof**: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R$. Given a fixed $t \in \Bbb R$, let
$$A_t= \{B \subseteq \Bbb R : t+B \in \mathcal{B} \}$$

Let us prove that $A_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

1. $\emptyset \in A_t$. In fact, $t+\emptyset = \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}$.
2. If $B \in A_t$ then $t+B \in  \mathcal{B}$. So,
   $ t+B^c = (t+B)^c \in \mathcal{B}$. So, $B^c \in A_t$.
3. If, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $B_n \in A_t$ then  for all $n \in \Bbb N$,  $t+ B_n \in \mathcal{B}$. So $ t+ \bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n(t+B_n) \in \mathcal{B}$. So, $\bigcup_n B_n \in A_t$.

So, $A_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now note that, for all open sets $O$ , $t+O$ is also an open set and thus $t+O \in \mathcal{B}$. So, for all open set $O$ , $O \in A_t$.

It follows that $\mathcal{B} \subseteq A_t$

Since this is true for any $t \in \Bbb R$, we have proved that if $B\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a Borel set then $t+B$ also be Borel set, for any $t\in \Bbb R$.

**Remark 1**: I answered the question as it is asked.

1. If you know that translations are continuous and that continuous functions are Borel measurable, then your question becomes trivial as a consequence of the fact that the translation by $-t$ is continuous and so Borel measurable.
2. If you know that the addition of two Borel measurable functions is a Borel measurable function, then you question also becomes trivial.

However, I suppose you are just asking for a direct proof that if $B\subseteq \Bbb R$ is a Borel set then $t+B$ also is a Borel set, for any $t\in \Bbb R$, without using any extra results.

**Remark 2**:

1. To prove that any continuous function $f$ is Borel measurable is to prove that $A =\{ B \subseteq \Bbb R : f^{-1}(B) \text{ is Borel } \}$
   is a sigma-algebra containing all the open sets. Such proof is totally similar to the proof above in my answer.
2. To prove that, given two measurable functions $f$ and $g$, their addition $f+g$ is Borel measurable is actually a little bit trickier.

Comment: Thank you @Ramiro, That explains a lot. Can I use this approach prove $tB$ is Borel measurable for any Borel set $B$. This is dilation.

Comment: I'll try to do it by continuity method. define $f:tx\rightarrow cx$ since f is continuos and $f^-1(B)=tB$  then   $tB$ is measurable.

Comment: @ShanOH You can use this approach to prove $tB$ is Borel measurable.   On the other hand the continuity method will require multiplying by $t^{-1}$, so it only works for $t \ne 0$.

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

$t+B=f^{-1}(B)$ where $f:x\mapsto x-t$ is clearly measurable (sum of the identity map $x\mapsto x$ and the constant map $x\mapsto -t$), hence $t+B$ is a Borel set.

Comment: Hello Will, how $f:x\rightarrow x-t$ is measurable. I don't quit get that

Comment: Indeed, "$x \mapsto x-t$ is Borel measurable" is merely a restatement of the problem

Comment: Well, it is continuous and so measurable (presumably indicated by "clearly" in this answer). I like this clean answer (+1).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The answer simply claims that "$f:x\mapsto x-t$ is clearly measurable", without any further explanation. In fact, to prove that $f:x\mapsto x-t$  is Borel measurable is merely a restatement of the problem (as GEdgar pointed out).

Comment: @Will now I understand your approach.

Comment: as @SeverinSchraven says, it is continuous and therefore measurable. Or more simply, it is the sum of two obviously measurable maps, namely the identity map $x\mapsto x$ and the constant map $x\mapsto-t$.

Comment: @Ramiro You are right. I guess I lost my sense of what is clear. I simply prefer to use continuity than to the more complicated approach using the sigma-algebra (which clearly is a matter of taste).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I understand. However: 1.the OP have asked how to prove using sigma-algebra. 2. To use the continuity is "simpler" just because it "hides" the work with sigma-algebra that is needed to prove that if $f$ is a continuous function then it is  Borel measurable. It "hides" the work of proving that $A =\{ B : f^{-1}(B) \text{ is Borel } \} $ is a sigma-algebra  containing all the open sets, which was exactly what the OP was asking for in the specific case of translation by $-t$.

Comment: @Ramiro Clearly true what you are saying. However, I would guess that this is a fact that should be known to the OP and thus it should be "easier" (we don't have to redo everything just because we rephrase things).

Comment: Once again, $x\mapsto x-t$ is measurable because it is the sum of the identity map $x\mapsto x$ and the constant map $x\mapsto -t$, whose measurability is straightforward. Isn't it simple enough? ...

Comment: @Will  Your answer is simple, if the OP knows that continuous function are Borel measurable or if he knows that the sum of two Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable. However, both results are "more advanced" than the result being asked by the OP.  By the question asked, we can not infer that the OP knows how prove those two "more advanced" results.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven By the question asked, we can not infer that the OP knows how to prove that continuous functions are Borel measurable. Also, the OP explicitly asked how to prove the result using sigma-algebra. But I agree that it is a matter of perception.